# How to handle exception with Spring/JPA?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, exception, spring-data-jpa

I want to handle this exception:

```
try {
      save = usersRepository.save(user);
}
catch (Exception gottaCatchEmAll){
      System.out.println("got it");
}
```

in logs I see:

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

How can I catch it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest writing advice handler class for dealing with any exceptions. For example I assume your exception is of type `DataIntegrityViolationException`. That will be wrapped in some kind of DTO which can be returned to front-end or do what you like with it.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandler {

  @ExceptionHandler(DataIntegrityViolationException.class)
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
  @ResponseBody
  public ErrorDto processConstraintError(DataIntegrityViolationException ex) {
    return new ErrorDto(ex.getMessage());
  }

}
```

No need to try-catch anything from JPA.

Comment: I added this to my project by nothing happen, how to activate it for particular controller?

Comment: It is not tied to specific controller unless you specifcy `basePackages` on the advice annotation. You need to show your Spring configuration where to scan for this package though.

Comment: at startup I see in logs: Looking for ControllerAdvice: : Detected ExceptionHandler methods in ExceptionHandler, I use spring boot + spring security, I dont have any additional configuration  only spring.jpa.show-sql=true

Comment: For Spring Boot it should then just work as is. Just make sure that you use the appropriate exception which you need to handle :) My example was just an assumption, could be wrong one.

Comment: I did a lot of tests. I try to handle java.lang.Exception. It work for all Exception  but it does not work for: .MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row:, any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Can you try just handling superclass of that which would be `SQLException.class` ?

Comment: thanks now it working I had ProfilerAspect who caught all sql exceptions